# Haxe: How do I repeat a string n times

Tags: haxe

I want to repeat a character or string, such as "Z", a specific number of times (let's say 5 times). I could easily do it in a loop, of course, like this:

```
var combined = "";
for(i in 0...5) {
    combined += "Z";
}
trace(combined); // ZZZZZ
```

But is there a function in the standard library, or a some kind of special syntax sugar, that would allow me to do it as a one liner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways it could be done in a one-liner.

1. From the standard library, you could call [`StringTools.rpad()`](https://api.haxe.org/StringTools.html#rpad) or [`StringTools.lpad()`](https://api.haxe.org/StringTools.html#lpad), starting with an empty string (it only works if the second argument is length 1, though):

```
var combined = StringTools.rpad("", "Z", 5);
```

2. You could use [Array comprehension](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-array-comprehension.html) to add the character to an array *n* times, and then call [`Array.join()`](https://api.haxe.org/Array.html#join) with an empty string as the separator:

```
var combined = [for (i in 0...5) "Z"].join("");
```